# Add 0 when ever the value is 12 character

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, numeric-data

I extracting a column from a file with different values, some of them are 11 character to 13, but whenever the value is 11 I need to add a 0 in front.

```
awk -F, '{print $1 }' $FILE | \
 awk '{printf("%04d%s\n", NR, $0)}' | \
 awk '{printf("%-12s\n", $0) }'

82544990078
82544990757
899188001738
9337402002723
9337402002686
9337402002747
812153010733
852271005003
89000118359
```

It should look like this:

```
082544990078
082544990757
899188001738
9337402002723
9337402002686
9337402002747
812153010733
852271005003
089000118359
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
$ awk 'length() == 11 { $0 = "0" $0 } 1' < input
082544990078
082544990757
899188001738
9337402002723
9337402002686
9337402002747
812153010733
852271005003
089000118359
```

Comment: You answered more quickly than me, I deleted my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

`... | sed 's/^(.\{11,11\})$/0\1/' | ...`